# How do I dynamically add my Ngrok tunnel to config.hosts in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ngrok

I'm trying to whitelist my ngrok tunnel hostname in `config.hosts` but it changes every time I start Ngrok. Is there a way to get the public url of my Ngrok tunnel so that I don't have to use `hosts.clear`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply configure `config/environments/development.rb` like so:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  ...

  config.hosts << '.ngrok.io'
end
```

This will allow requests from any subdomain of `ngrok.io`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't actually remember why I didn't go for a solution this simple. May not have been possible at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Ngrok has a built in JSON API that can be found on `localhost:4040/api/tunnels`.

```
# lib/ngrok_client.rb
module NgrokClient
  def self.tunnels
    response = Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels'))
    begin
      JSON.parse(response).dig("tunnels")
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      Rails.logger.error %q{
        Failed to parse reponse from Ngroks internal API. Are you sure its running?
      }
    end
  end
  def self.public_urls
    tunnels.select do |h|
      # TODO - don't hardcode the host name
      h.dig("config", "addr") == "http://localhost:3000"
    end.map { |h| URI(h["public_url"]).hostname }.uniq
  end
end
```

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  require 'ngrok_client'
  config.hosts += NgrokClient.public_urls
end
```

There is also the [ngrok-tunnel](https://github.com/bogdanovich/ngrok-tunnel) gem that can be used to start ngrok from the middleware layer as a less hacky soultion.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361487/14001685 didn't work for me (Rails 6) but regex did.

```
config.hosts << %r{.+\.ngrok.io$}
```

Comment: Its works on Rails 7.0.3 application to...

Answer (score 1):

**Simply configure `config/environments/development.rb` like so:**

`config.hosts << /.*\.ngrok\.io$/`

**This will allow requests from any subdomain dynamic regular expression of ngrok.io.**

Comment: I'm getting undefined method hosts.